# Updated Symfony's fixture file but still missing some information!

Tags: php, symfony1

I created a fixture file and the information is effectively updated in the database (I can see it in phpmyadmin), but when I open the page in the web browser there is some information lost:

```
JobeetJob:
  job_sensio_labs:
    JobeetCategory: programming
    type:         full-time
    company:      Sensio Labs
    logo:         sensio-labs.gif
    url:          http://www.sensiolabs.com/
    position:     Web Developer
    location:     Paris, France
    description:  |
      You've already developed websites with symfony and you want to work
      with Open-Source technologies. You have a minimum of 3 years
      experience in web development with PHP or Java and you wish to
      participate to development of Web 2.0 sites using the best
      frameworks available.
    how_to_apply: |
      Send your resume to fabien.potencier [at] sensio.com
    is_public:    true
    is_activated: true
    token:        job_sensio_labs
    email:        job@example.com
    expires_at:   '2009-02-28'

  job_extreme_sensio:
    JobeetCategory:  design
    type:         part-time
    company:      Extreme Sensio
    logo:         extreme-sensio.gif
    url:          http://www.extreme-sensio.com/
    position:     Web Designer
    location:     Paris, France
    description:  |
```

In this case, **job_extreme_sensio** doesn't appear in the appication (even after doing `php symfony doctrine:data-load`).

Is this a cache problem? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Is the list filtered? Your second row doesn't list these fields :

```
is_public:    true
is_activated: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you need to clear cache every time after changing DB